# Bootstrap : fontawesome icons not acting responsive

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am  using font awesome icons in my bootstrap page like this

```
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
  </div>


  .interests .fa {
    font-size: 80px;
    background: #e2b124;
    border-radius: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

now in mobile view i expect  this div to be in center of  the page but this is how it  acts in mobile view

[image]

i tried to  use `margin: 0 auto;`but that does not work either . Pleas help me ot get  this wroking

Comment: Can we see a bit more of your code? Where are you using `.interests`?

Comment: <div class="row interests">  ..........

Comment: Have you tried adding `text-center` to your list of classes on the `col-xs-12` div?

Comment: `<div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is simply modifying the div to be:

```
  <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
    <i class="fa fa-camera"></i>
  </div>
```

You can see it in action [here](http://www.bootply.com/T8kiAWLLVH).